# why does timezone aware datetime have 2 times in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

I set a date to midnight like this:

```
user_tz = timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
day_start = user_tz.localize(entered_at.replace(hour=00, minute=00))
```

I print the date and it looks like so:

> start date: 2014-08-21 00:00:00-07:00

What is the -7:00 at the end and how do I make it go away?

Comment: -7:00 is the offset of the your local Pacific timezone relative to UTC -- it's 7 hours behind.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered by [**this**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/#fixtures) part of the Django documentation. In short, it's the **UTC offset**: the time difference between the timezone you have selected and UTC.

To "make it go away", convert the *aware* datetime to a *naive* datetime, or set `user_tz` to the UTC timezone.